# php display information from string

Tags: php

I have this code that gets the IP address and Latitude and Longitude of the user. However I am wanting ti display it on a map if it finds the lat and long.

```
$theirip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$fileinfo = file_get_contents("http://api.easyjquery.com/ips/?ip=".$theirip."&full=true");
```

This outputs a string like this.

> {"IP":"000.000.00.000","continentCode":"Unknown","continentName":"Unknown","countryCode2":"Unknown","COUNTRY":"Unknown","countryCode3":"Unknown","countryName":"Unknown","regionName":"Unknown","cityName":"Unknown","cityLatitude":0,"cityLongitude":0,"countryLatitude":0,"countryLongitude":0,"localTimeZone":"Unknown","localTime":"0"}

I am wanting to retrieve just the cityLatitude and cityLongitude from this. I have researched some and tried some different code.

```
$lat = $fileinfo -> {"cityLatitude"};
```

but i'm not quite sure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a JSONObject... just use the json_decode() to get data from it

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/) string, you can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to pasre it

```
$obj = json_decode($fileinfo);
$lat = $obj -> {"cityLatitude"};
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to decode the JSON, it should work fine.
trying from here its working just fine...

try using your IP instead of $theirip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Answer (score 0):

You're using PHP right? It should be

```
$info = json_decode($fileinfo);
$citylatitude = $info->cityLatitude;
```